# Handling errors in Promise.all - promise rejection + type error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have few `Promise.all` functions:

```
const fn = async () => {
   await Promise.all(first());
   await Promise.all(second());
   await Promise.all(third());
}
```

`first`, `second` and `third` functions looks almost the same together.

**`first`** function:

```
const first = async () => {
   const oldUsers = await User.find(...);

   return Array.isArray(oldUsers) ? oldUsers.map(async (user) => {
      await User.updateOne({ _id: user._id }, { ... });

      await transporter.sendMail(sendMail(user));
   }) : [];
};
```

#### My problem:

When starting the app and calling `fn` function, only first `Promise.all` is success (user is updated and mail is sent), but the `second` and `third` is not even called.

In console, I got error:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: undefined is not a function`

**Im struggling with it whole day**, what should I do, so the all three `Promise.all` are finished successfully? Looking for help, thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems like you're calling a function that doesn't exist - without more details/stacktraces I can't say more

Comment: @Snapstromegon I can guarantee you that all these three functions inside `Promise.all` exists and they are functions... :(

Comment: Is it possible, that one of the functions inside second or third don't exist?
Undefined is not a function means that somewhere an undefined value gets called as a function and a stacktrace would really help

Comment: @Snapstromegon yet still every function is defined :(

Comment: Are you sure, that the execution of await Promise.all(first()); finishes?

Comment: @Snapstromegon Hmm, I dont know if it finishes, but these two `await` functions are finished successfully (`User.update()` and `.sendMail`)

Comment: @Snapstromegon `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)`

Comment: @Snapstromegon I got it fixed, thank you for your help =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `Promise.all` takes an array of promises, but your `first()` function is `async` and therefore returns a promise for something. That promise is not iterable, so `Promise.all` fails. You could fix it by doing

```
await Promise.all(await first());
```

but really you should move the `Promise.all` into the `first` function itself:

```
async function first() {
  const oldUsers = await User.find(...);

  return Array.isArray(oldUsers)
    ? Promise.all(oldUsers.map(async (user) => {
        await User.updateOne({ _id: user._id }, { ... });
        await transporter.sendMail(sendMail(user));
      }))
    : [];
}
```

```
async function fn() {
   await first();
   await second();
   await third();
}
```